# Error 500 on server with ajax (send method)

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I use Javascript and AJAX to send some informations. The code below works on my local machine but not on my server.

```
var str = "/Nouvelle_Fiche" + "/" + id_fiche + "/" + id_process + "/" + type_process + "/" + id_impact + "/" + id_auteur + "/" + id_situation + "/" + questionnaires;

xmlhttp.open("POST", str, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send();
```

I have an error 500 "Internal Server Error" with the line "xmlhttp.send();". Can you help me please ? Thank you !

Comment: do `console.log(str);` and paste here

Comment: you need to debug the server side code where your ajax request is being sent

Comment: The str value is : "/Nouvelle_Fiche/17/13766/I/43/1162/1/2_"

Comment: The HTTP status code 500 is sent from the server and has nothing to do with the JS. You will have to view the error logs of whatever webserver you are using.

Comment: Thank's but I can't debug the server side because I don't have access to the graphic interface. It's not me who manage the server.

Answer (score 1):

Try to send `data` as json if you can or send `null` in `ajax.send` functions.
Try to change Content-type.

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("GET", url, true);
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
ajax.send( data );

ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
    console.log(ajax.response);
  }
};
```